# Add 'active' class to a mapped item causes all items to have class active

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I `onClick` add the class to only the item clicked? The below code is sufficient in adding/removing the class `active` but adds to all items in mapped `array

```
{tourDetails.map(({ node: questions })=> (
  <div key={questions.id} className="toggle">
    <div onClick={this.handleToggleActive} className={`toggle-title ${this.state.questionActive ? 'active' : ''}`}>
      <h3><i></i><span className="title-name">{questions.question}</span></h3>
   </div>
   <div className={`toggle-inner ${this.state.questionActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html:questions.answer.childMarkdownRemark.html,
     }}
   />
  </div>
))}
```

The class Active is added by setting the state in the component as

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    questionActive: false
  }
  this.handleToggleActive = this.handleToggleActive.bind(this)
}

handleToggleActive() {
  this.setState({
    questionActive: !this.state.questionActive
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there are many ways to do this here's one of them.

Pass the clicked id to the state then compear it in map id.

```
onClick={this.handleToggleActive.bind(this, questions)}
```

I prefer you always to use arrow function to setState

```
handleToggleActive = (questions) => {
  this.setState({
    questionActive: questions.id
  })
}
```

Compear the state with current id in map

```
className={`toggle-title ${questions.id === this.state.questionActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
```

> No need to bind `handleToggleActive` in `constructor`

I did an example

[image: Edit 8xp0xjqow2]

Comment: Sorry to come back to you Liam but noticed that your solution doesn't remove the `active` class `onClick`. Wondered if you knew an easy way to achieve this. Cheers.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help :-) Do you want to remove active class when press double click?

Comment: When do you want to remove the active class?

Comment: Thank you. I am using as an accordion and would like to toggle on and off `onClick`. So when a user clicks the active class is added, click again and it is removed.

Comment: However, also remove the active class when clicking another item.

Comment: Thank you very much - will do so now!